# Oppogram - Anagram of the opposite

Tags: wordplay, anagram, oppogram

Let's define an **Oppogram** as **an anagram of opposites**. Provided the words below, find their opposites, and then answer the question using an anagram of the words you found.

> **Example**
>   Who is Pepper's best friend?
>      `first`
>   *answer*: `first -> last -> salt`

---

> Who is this famous person?

```
  dry young alpha-male
```

or

```
  collect sea preserve
```

<sup>*Note*: Two word sets have been provided that will each individually reach the same conclusion. The pair can be used to help you determine that your opposite selections were correct since they will be anagrams of each other.</sup>

**Hint 1:**

> The opposite for dry and the opposite for collect only differ by one letter.

**Hint 2:**

> Young > old, sea > land

Comment: I'm not sure how the original was unclear, but hopefully I have reworded it in a way that is more understandable while not fundamentally changing the puzzle.

Comment: the original was beyond unclear for me. Now I get it, good edit. The example is key.

Comment: I have posted [another](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/31696/16717) of this type, hopefully we can get more. Thank you!

Comment: Is *"Oppogram"* a word in the Urban Dictionary? ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is:

> Donald Trump

because

> dry young alpha-male = damp old runt

and

> collect sea preserve = dump land rot

Comment: `waste` -> `rot`?

Comment: Yes - my mistake in filling in answer - I will correct if OK.

Comment: I refuse to upvote this answer on principle, but it does appear to be the correct answer.

Comment: Totally nailed it!

Answer (score 2):

> WET-OLD-OMEGA-WOMAN

or

> DISPERSE-LAND-ENDANGER
>  DISPERSE-LAND-WASTE

Comment: Hey you're going along the right track.  Some of the opposites are correct!

Comment: opp of male is female

Comment: Alpha-male seems one word so I doubt that omega women is the right opposite

Answer (score 1):

No answer yet, but here are the opposites that I've found so far which look like having common letters (some taken from @Van.Graaf's answer):-

> dry - wet, watery; humid, moist, damp
>  young - old, elder; aged
>  alpha-male - beta-male; subordinate, deputy
>
>  collect - distribute, disburse, disperse, dismantle; scatter
>  sea - land; shore, harbo(u)r, earth
>  preserve - destroy, waste; endanger
>
>  Notes: There is only one word with 'm' or 'g' in the second list, and none with 'f'.

Comment: A couple of the opposites are a bit tricky and not entirely antonyms.  But using the nature of the puzzle shouldn't be too hard to figure out.