# Three linked oppograms

Tags: wordplay, anagram, literature, oppogram

Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30180/16717) where an oppogram was defined as an anagram of opposites

For example:

> $\color{blue}{ratify }\space\color{red}{smart}\space\color{green}{peace}\rightarrow\color{blue}{deny}\space\color{red}{slow}\space\color{green}{war} = \color{red}{W}\color{green}{a}\color{blue}{yne}\text{'}\color{red}{s}\space\color{green}{W}\color{red}{o}\color{green}{r}\color{red}{l}\color{blue}{d}$

The following three oppograms **are linked by a common author**:

- Order from nothing
- Wild whole no
- Received low out

Of what are they oppograms?

Comment: So, first we make anagram out of these three, then antonym of each words, and then connect three sub-answers... right?

Comment: @ABcDexter other way around - opposite of each word first, then anagram the group of three words. then each anagrammed thing is connected by a single other thing.

Comment: @ABcDexter first we find antonyms then we perform rearangement

Comment: I apologize, am very sleepy :-/

Comment: Hopefully this will encourage more, but tougher ones :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely, we all love anagrams, dont we :D

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yeah these are fun. However, once you find one of the oppograms the others become a lot easier. Gamow was faster by the way, so I think he deserves the tick

Comment: @Wu33o you beat him to get all three (Gamow posted an incomplete answer and finished it off 2 mins after you posted your complete answer).

Comment: @ABcDexter [Seedy Wo](http://i.imgur.com/YoyY6yo.gif)!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The author is:

> Stephen King

Oppograms:
*Order from nothing:*

> Mess to all -> Salem's Lot

*Wild whole no:*

> Tame part yes -> Pet sematary

*Received low out:*

> Sent high in -> The Shining

Answer (score 9):

The common author is

> Stephen King

---

Order from nothing:

> mess to all = "Salem's lot"

Wild whole no:

> Tame part yes = "Pet Sematary"

Received low out:

> Sent high in = "The Shining"

Comment: Ah you beat me to it! Well done :)

Comment: Sorry, I accepted @Wu33o's since he beat you to Order from nothing. But well done!