# Oppograms - what comes next?

Tags: wordplay, anagram, oppogram

**What comes next in this sequence?**

- Refunds Cruelty Refund
- Unexcited Tingle
- Forgets Yon Attracts

[What](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30180/oppogram-anagram-of-the-opposite) is an [Oppogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31696/three-linked-oppograms)?

Bonus points for answering in the form of an oppogram, however you might want to put the actual answer in a separate spoiler tag.

Hint:

- > They're people.
- > The third one is easy, but "Forgets" could be "Separates" or "Undoes"

Comment: Can we get a hint? :-)

Comment: @Eutherpy In the past I've made hints that imo are too obvious, so I'm being more careful this time. But yes, a small one.

Comment: A one word opposite of forget, separate, and undo could be connect, perhaps.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 Though OP could mean that those three words' opposites just contain the same group of letters.

Comment: I cannot fathom three different words respectively opposite of forget, separate, and undo which have all the same letters. o.O

Comment: Do you think you could give letter counts? As it stands now it is pretty broad (a lot of synonyms, a heck of a lot of "famous" people), and most of the words don't have extremely obvious opposites (i.e. up -> down)

Comment: I agree with @GordonAllocman here - Oppograms are unsolvable without letter counts.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure the answer is 'neglect, quiet, rear':

> David Tennant - Next actor who played Doctor Who

Refunds Cruelty Refund

> Sylvester McCoy - Costs, Mercy, Levy

Unexcited Tingle - thanks to @Will

> Paul McGann - Uncalm, Pang

Forgets Yon Attracts

> Christopher Eccleston - Concocts, Hither, Repels

Massive props to @GordonK

Comment: How about `uncalm pang`?

Comment: Now I guess people can solve my oppogram too! :)

Comment: Nice one: `attend din van`. :)

Comment: @Will You got it!

Comment: I'm sure this is right, but how is "concocts" the opposite of "forgets"? I don't see it at all.

Comment: Second definition on google - Create or devise (a story or plan).
"his cronies concocted a simple plan".
synonyms: make up, think up, dream up, fabricate, invent, contrive, manufacture, trump up; devise, create, form, formulate, fashion, forge; hatch, brew, plot, scheme; informal: cook up;
"I wonder what story she has concocted to explain her presence"

Comment: It's not a straight opposite, but to concoct a plan/forget a plan is close enough in my opinion. I feel Uncalm, Pang is ropier!

Comment: I know what "concoct" means (stories as well as physical things), but I don't see how concocting something is the opposite of forgetting it. Oh well, never mind; this obviously wasn't too big an obstacle to solving the puzzle. I am very impressed.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, cheers, but Gordon K got me most of the way there!

Comment: I'm impressed by both of you.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer, a stretch at best, but hopefully pointing someone in the correct direction:

•Forgets Yon Attracts

Taking the second word, *Yon*, first. This is a very unusual choice, suggesting that the word we're looking for is well-know for being the opposite of *Yon*. The only thing that springs to mind is:

> Hither, as in "Hither and Yon"

Now looking at *Attracts*, the opposite that seems most likely to me is:

> Repels

Playing with the letters from these two words I was able to come up with:

> _hrist_pher Lee

This is only missing 2 letters to give the name of someone famous and, at a stretch, a possible opposite of separates is:

> co- meaning together (e.g. co-conspirator)

This means that the third person on the list is:

> [**Christopher Lee**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Lee) and the sequence might possibly be something to do with actors who have played bond villains or sith lords, however Christopher Lee's credits are incredibly long, so they could be almost anything.

---

**Alternative Theory**

> Looking for other famous Christophers who have the letters EEL in their surname, the only one that jumped out at me was [Christopher Eccleston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Eccleston), which would give "actors who have played The Doctor" as a good sequence to investigate, however I couldn't get the letters COCCSTON to make a word that means the opposite of forgets, separates or undoes. I Also couldn't get the other clues to match with Paul McGann and Sylvester McCoy or David Tennant and Matt Smith.

Comment: Would you reward someone who concocts a word for your alternative theory..

Comment: @Arth Well spotted.