# More linked oppograms

Tags: wordplay, music, anagram, oppogram

Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30180/oppogram-anagram-of-the-opposite) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31696/three-linked-oppograms) puzzle: more oppograms!

---

An oppogram is an anagram of opposites. First find the opposites of the words below, then form the *title of a song* by making an anagram of these opposites (for more information and examples, see the other oppogram puzzles). The oppograms **are linked by a common music artist**:

- Stop aggravate distant (2; 16)
- Bright incapable silence (3; 14)
- Irritate north liberate yang (6; 21)

The numbers between brackets indicates the number of words and the total number of letters in the song names.

What are the "oppogrammed" songs, and what is the name of the music artist?

Comment: anagram of each opposite or as a group?

Comment: You have to make an anagram of each group of opposites. For examples you can take a look at one of the other oppogram puzzles

Comment: I must say, I'm starting to tire of these "oppograms".  The first couple were a novelty, but now they're starting to become tedious.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I'm sorry you don't like it, although nobody forces you to try to solve them. But sure, no more oppograms then

Comment: @Wu33o I'm only one person.  Who knows if anyone shares my opinion.  I've seen at least on comment on a previous oppogram stating that the commenter really enjoyed solving them, so don't stop just on my account.

Comment: @Wu33o My issue is that this is the type of puzzle that anyone can generate with a minimum of effort, which makes me worry that the site will just be flooded with them.  They're not especially clever or difficult to make, but that doesn't mean no one enjoys them or finds them entertaining.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I know they _can_ be created with a minimum of effort, which is why I tried to put in a lot more effort in order to make a more challenging puzzle. I interpreted your comment this way because I don't see what else you were trying to achieve with it, but of course I can be mistaken. Anyway, once again I'm sorry you don't like it.

Comment: Maybe you should post more information, like a total letter count for each set, for example. As it is, there are too many possible antonyms and too many possible anagrams to solve this without being able to read your mind.

Comment: Piggy backing of what @question_asker said, I tried putting in what I thought the most obvious opposites are for the last clue in an anagram solver, and got 78949 different anagrams. Obviously less of these are actually song titles, but that's just one possible combination of words, and these words don't exactly have blatant opposites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not possibly have figured this out without all the help of the people here. I give credit to the discussion for the word count and letter count hints, and @Trenin for his partial answer leading me to a reverse engineering approach. However, we now have a possible solution.

Stop aggravate distant (2; 16)

> play appease close => **Apocalypse Please**

Bright incapable silence (3; 14)

> cloudy fit noise => **City of Delusion**

Irritate north liberate yang (6; 21)

> South yin alleviate hold => **Hate this and I'll love you** (Credit to @Trenin)

These three songs had this band in common:

> **MUSE**

Comment: Nice work.  I was stuck on Bright -> Dark/Dim.  Wouldn't have thought of "Stop->Play"

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at the last one.

```
Irritate north liberate yang (6; 21)
```

> Both "North" and "Yang" have the obvious opposites of "South" and "Yin" which contain 8 letters total.

This leave 13 letters for the opposites of liberate and irritate.

Here are the possibilities:

> alleviate  hold/keep
>     appease/assuage/comfort/delight/mollify/placate detain

The first possibility is:

> "South yin alleviate hold" which gives an anagram of "Hate this and I'll love you" by Muse.

However, I cannot find any other songs by this artist which fit the word/letter requirements.

Comment: Apocalypse Please {2;16} and City of Delusion {3;14} match the other oppograms' word/letter requirements.

Comment: Also, "Bedroom Acoustics" and "Ruled by Secrecy".