# Science Oppograms

Tags: wordplay, anagram, science, oppogram

Here come more [Oppograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30180/22168), this time science-related courtesy of our fortnightly challenge.

The rules: In each set of words, find the opposite of each word, then anagram the letters of all opposites to get one term.

The oppograms below form one physics term, one chemistry term, and one biology term (not necessarily in that order).

> 1. abnormal original ignore plagiarise (2 words, 16 letters)
> 2. imagined water seldom [sent items] (2 words, 20 letters, "sent items" has one opposite)
> 3. straighten lazy shack (2 words, 14 letters)

Hint 1: Which is which term

> #1 is physics, #2 is biology, #3 is chemistry

Hint 2: Clarification on some words people seem to be having trouble on

> Instead of lazy, I could have used dull.
>  Instead of ignore, I could have used dismiss.
>  Abnormal is not average.
>  Original is a noun in this context, not an adjective.

Comment: u sure, there are 14 letters in the last one?? I get 15...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Also, I will put up some hints later today.

Answer (score 6):

Guess for 2: imagined water seldom [sent items]

> "occured* ice daily inbox"
>  anagrams to: **deoxyribonucleic acid** (2 words, 20 letters)
>  I know the correct spelling should be "occurred", but I don't know how to spoiler comments to ask about this, so I'm posting as a WIP answer instead..

Comment: This is correct. Not sure how I missed that glaringly obvious typo though, good job for figuring it out anyway!

Comment: Hooray, thanks for the confirmation! I'll keep thinking on the other two..

Answer (score 3):

My guess for number 1 is:

> Terminal Velocity

abnormal

> norm

original

> tail (original meaning beginning or first, tail meaning end or last)

ignore

> levy (to impose)

plagiarize

> cite

Yielding:

> norm tail levy cite -> terminal velocity

Comment: This was not my intended answer, but it (mostly) fits.

Answer (score 1):

This a wiki post to gather ideas. Feel free to use it in your answer !

### First Oppogram

abnormal original ignore plagiarise (2 words, 16 letters)

#### Opposite ideas :

> abnormal -> normal (6) // typic (5) // usual (5) // norm (4)
> original -> copy (4) // used (4) // old (3) // tail (4) // banal (5) // fake (4) // faux (4)
> ignore/dismiss -> know (4) // heed (4) // attend (6) // note (4) // keep (4)
> plagiarise -> create (6) // renew (5) // give (4) // cite (4)

#### Word ideas :

Chemistry terms (16 letters) from [wikipedia glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chemistry_terms)

> activation energy
>  addition reaction
>  buffered solution
>  chemical reaction
>  conjugated system
>  molecular formula
>  molecular orbital
>  organic chemistry
>  Quantum mechanics
>  radioactive decay
>  reactivity series

Physics (16) from [glossary of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_physics)

> Absolute Humidity
>  Absolute pressure
>  Adiabatic cooling
>  Adiabatic heating
>  Angular frequency
>  Astronomical unit
>  Avogadro constant
>  Babinet Principle
>  Centrifugal force
>  Centripetal force
>  Covalent compound
>  Definite integral
>  Emission spectrum
>  Fermats principle
>  Hamilton princple
>  Laplace transform
>  Linear elasticity
>  Liouville theorem
>  Mass spectrometry
>  Materials science
>  Maxwell equations
>  Mechanical filter
>  Molecular physics
>  Phase equilibrium
>  Physical quantity
>  Quantum mechanics
>  Rotational energy
>  Thermal radiation
>  Utility frequency
>  Variable resistor

### Third Oppogram :

straighten lazy shack (2 words, 14 letters)

#### Opposite ideas

> straighten -> bend (4) // move (4) // curve (5) // twist (5) // warp (4) // fold (4)
>  lazy / dull -> fresh (5) // lively (6) // active (6) // keen (4) // eager (5)
>  shack -> manor (5) // castle (6) // mansion (7) // villa (5) // home (4) // house (5) // palace (6)

#### Word ideas

Chemistry (14) from [wikipedia glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chemistry_terms)

> activity series
>  electric charge
>  saline solution
>  transition metal
>  vapour pressure

Physics (14) from [glossary of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_physics)

> Absolute motion
>  Amorphous solid
>  Bessel function
>  Brownian motion
>  Circular motion
>  Current density
>  Elastic modulus
>  Electric charge
>  Escape velocity
>  Fluid mechanics
>  Linear actuator
>  Machine element
>  Newtonian fluid
>  Nuclear physics
>  Planck constant
>  Quantum physics
>  Rydberg formula
>  Solid mechanics
>  Simple harmonic
>  Structural load
>  Surface tension
>  Tensile modulus
>  Volta potential

Comment: I will say that the correct physics term is listed here, but the chemistry one isn't.

Comment: @BusinessCat could you please clarify whether the correct physics term is listed in the first set of physics words (the 16 letter set) or the second set (the 14 letter set) ..... since adding and removing plurals could easily make a 14 letter word a 16 letter one and vice versa